# How do I prompt users to review the application only when they are connected to a network?

Tags: iphone, ios

Just like other developers, I would like users to review my app in the app store. However, from my personal experience, it is extremely annoying when apps ask me to review but I don't have Wi-Fi. Is there a way to tell when you have internet connection (without leaving the app) so that I can make it only ask them when they have Wi-Fi/3G?

Answer (score 5):

You should look at the [Reachability sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) for an example of how to check the network connection status. Some people even copy Reachability.h/m from this sample into their own projects and use it.

Comment: +1: beat me to it by about 8 seconds. :) @OP, yes Reachability is the way to go, and the sample code shows you how to use it almost exactly. just do the check as in the sample, and if you have inet pop up a UIAlertView with the button to go to the app store (should probably warn them it will close the app).